# Where to store settings for public Shopify App

Tags: shopify, settings

I am developing a public Shopify app.
Where should I store app custom settings? Does Shopify have some API to store custom settings?
In case I save settings in my custom database how can I load them in my embedded app?

Comment: If there are a lot of data then go with a custom solution like separate DB else you can using meta fields to store the data.

Comment: do you develop an admin app or front end?

Comment: I am developing an admin app.

Answer (score 0):

Store your app settings in your database. The embedded app you're creating should handle authentication properly and your app should access the store settings and any other store data only when you're sure the app is loaded by the client that has the right to access this data.

Here are the links that might be useful:

[Shopify App CLI](https://shopify.dev/tools/cli)
[Authenticate with OAuth](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth)
[Building embedded apps using session tokens](https://shopify.dev/concepts/apps/building-embedded-apps-using-session-tokens)
[Build a Shopify App with Node and React Tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react)

Answer (score 0):

You should store your app settings in the store metafields.